# I am looking for the button images for fullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using a default version of the fullCalendar.  It is using the default gray buttons for the month/week/day buttons.

I've searched the .js and .css files, but I cannot find the button images anywhere...does anyone know where they are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think these are created using CSS effects.

Have a look at the content using Firebug tool.

The previous button is something like this.

```
<span class="fc-button-content">&nbsp;◄&nbsp;</span>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ya! Its in the JS code, its added as an ASCII charecter, you can over ride fc-button-content with css and your own button, colors, etc using !important